# How to "Go to definition" of a function using Visual Assist?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-assist

I am using Visual Assist for last couple of months. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> is very useful and fast in finding definition of anything **under cursor**.

But I am not able to figure out how to **Go to definition** by manually putting the function-name or class-name as text input (as we do while searching using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>).

What I am doing right now is using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and trying to look for *definition* from the *long list of string search result*. :(

I hope my requirement is clear.

Comment: There is `F12` for 'Go to definition' and `Ctrl+F12` for 'Go to Declaration' but I don't know a 'manually input finder' any other then the standard mentioned by you. http://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W191

Comment: If you right-click on variable name, it appears in your context menu the 'Go to definition' option?

Comment: Then, as a last solution, if anyone can give you any suggestion, consider to reinstall the visual assist.

Comment: @mtb But the question is that does even `F12` allow text input instead of under-cursor operation? It doesn't as much I have experience.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it doesn't have a text input. As I said in the first comment, I don't know other text input search then the standard with Ctrl+Shift+F.

Comment: What is wrong with "ctrl + comma" (navigate to)? This is the most powerful shortcut in VS...

Comment: @apr Does `ctrl+,` go to definition...?

Comment: The Visual Assist menu has an entry "Goto Member ...". If I understood your question correctly, that's what you're looking for. Unfortunately it doesn't have a keyboard shortcut (but I'm pretty sure this could be added somehow)

Comment: @MS82 "Goto Member" doesn't search at the Solution level, instead only searches in currently opened file.

Comment: F12 goes to the definition. Navigate to (ctrl + comma) brings up a search field with the scope of the entire solution. Navigate to search pattern matches files, classes, members etc. This one of the most powerful feature of VS (the only drawback that we cannot change to scope always search the entire solution). These are built-in features you don't need Visual Assist for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the *Whole Tomato Software* support team, I got the answer upon raising a [ticket](http://forums.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=12741).

Keyboard shortcut to "**Go To Definition**" with text input is:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

It is very fast and accurate.

To get an exact or strict match, use `.symbolname.`  as text-input in *Find Symbol* prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have been looking for the shortcut `VAssistX.GotoImplementation` instead. Edit it to a hotkey of your liking in Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Search for it and 'Assign' a hotkey after you press it. This is what I was looking for. At any rate I am adding this here in case the internet searchers (/googlers) stumble upon it.